# Function based letter guessing game

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to do a function based letter guessing game for a class project. I previously completed a program that would produce a random letter and now I need to make it function based however it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime> 
using namespace std;

void introduction();
//Display the introduction

int getNumberOfGames(int& number_of_games);
//Ask individual how many games they want to play
//

char compareTwoCharacters(char answer, char& guess);
//

char playOneGame(char answer);
//function returns true if user won;otherwise will return false. going to call the 3rd function to decide if correct or not



int main()
{
char alphabet [27];
int number_of_games;
char guess;
int games = 1;
char n = (char)(rand() % 26 + 1);
srand(time(0));


void introduction();
int getNumberOfGames(int);
char compareTwoCharacters(char,char);
char playOneGame(char);

    system("pause");

}

void introduction()
{
    cout<<"Weclome to the Letter Guessing game!\n";
    cout<<"You have 5 chances to guess each letter.\n \n";
    cout<<"Let's begin!\n";
    cout<<"**************************************************\n\n";

}

int getNumberOfGames(int& number_of_games)
{
    cout<<"How many games do you want to play? \n";
    cin >> number_of_games;
    return 0;

}

char compareTwoCharacters(char answer, char guess)
{
    cout << "Enter your guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    if (guess == answer)
        return 0;
    else if (guess < answer)
        return 2;
    else
        return -2;
}

char playOneGame(char answer)
{
    //return true is guess = answer otherwise return false
    return true;

    while (games <= number_of_games) 
    char answer = 97 + rand() % 27;
    cout << "Lets play game " << games++ << '\n';
    for (int number_of_guesses = 0; number_of_guesses < 5; number_of_guesses++)
    {

        cout << "Enter your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess > answer)
        {
            cout << "The letter you are trying to guess is before " << guess << "\n";

        }
        else if (guess < answer)
        {
            cout << "The letter you are trying to guess is after " << guess << "\n";

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Your guess is correct! \n";

            break;
        }

}
    cout << "The answer you were looking for was " << answer << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think in your code you want a block of code after `while (games <= number_of_games)` . So add the `{  }` to the right place.. right now the loop only covers this: `char answer = 97 + rand() % 27;`

Comment: This code has repetitive function declarations, invalid function calls, and syntax errors. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of syntactical errors in your code:

**Firstly**, your `srand(time(NULL))` function should come before you generate the random number, not after it. Therefore, you should move it so that your code looks like:

```
srand(time(NULL));
// Add the rest of your code here
char n = (char)(rand() % 26 + 1);
```

**Secondly**, the while-loop in the function `playOneGame()`:

```
while (games <= number_of_games)
```

Does not have an opening or closing curly brace to enclose all the code; hence the line that is right under the while-loop condition is considered to be a part of the while-loop. So you should add curly braces to the part of code you want to include in the while loop, something like:

```
while (games <= number_of_games)
{
    // Add necessary code
}
```

There are other logic and syntactical errors in your code, but depending on your your program, you may want to fix them accordingly, as there is no fixed answer for that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As many people have already said, there are a lot of syntactical errors in your code.

**First**, You should seed your random value generator (use `srand()`) before you use the `rand()` function. So, `srand(time(0))` should go before `char n = (char)(rand() % 26 + 1);`, not after.

**Second**, When you are calling you functions, you don't need to add the return types. For example, in your `main()` function, the function `void introduction();` should be changed to `introduction();`, same with the next 3 function calls (see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm).

**Third**, When calling functions, you need a parameter, not a type. For example, your function call `compareTwoCharacters(char,char);` should not have `char` as its parameters, but should have a variable or a literal like this: `compareTwoCharacters(n,'A');`. Make these changes in the 3 function calls you wrote.

**Forth**, In your `char compareTwoCharacters(char answer, char guess)` (Line 57) function, you are supposed to be returning a `char`, but in your code, you returned an integer: `return 0;` and `return 2;` and `return -2;`. Make sure that your return statements and return type match. This is the same issue in your `char playOneGame(char answer)` function; you are returning `true`, but the return type is a `char`.

**Fifth**, In your `char playOneGame(char answer)` function, you are missing your brackets for your while loop. If there are no brackets, it will only loop the next command, which is `char answer = 97 + rand() % 27;` and never end (infinite loop) because the exit condition is never reached.

**Sixth**, In the same function, the variable `game` is never declared. It was declared in a different function (`int games = 1;` in line 26), but as soon as you step out of that function, `game` ceases to exit (for more info: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm).

I fixed some of the errors, trying to keep the same general structure of your code and marked the changes with `// CHANGED`. However it may not be the way you intend for the program to run:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime> 
using namespace std;

void introduction();
//Display the introduction

int getNumberOfGames(int& number_of_games);
//Ask individual how many games they want to play
//

int compareTwoCharacters(char answer, char guess); // CHANGED
//

int playOneGame(int games, int number_of_games, char guess); // CHANGED
//function returns true if user won;otherwise will return false. going to call the 3rd function to decide if correct or not



int main()
{
    char alphabet [27];
    int number_of_games;
    char guess;
    int games = 1;
    srand(time(0)); // CHANGED
    char n = (char)(rand() % 26 + 1); // CHANGED

    introduction(); // CHANGED
    getNumberOfGames(number_of_games); // CHANGED
    compareTwoCharacters(n,'A'); // CHANGED
    playOneGame(games, number_of_games, guess); // CHANGED

    system("pause");

}

void introduction()
{
    cout<<"Weclome to the Letter Guessing game!\n";
    cout<<"You have 5 chances to guess each letter.\n \n";
    cout<<"Let's begin!\n";
    cout<<"**************************************************\n\n";

}

int getNumberOfGames(int& number_of_games)
{
    cout<<"How many games do you want to play? \n";
    cin >> number_of_games;
    return 0;

}

int compareTwoCharacters(char answer, char guess) // CHANGED
{
    cout << "Enter your guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    if (guess == answer)
        return 0;
    else if (guess < answer)
        return 2;
    else
        return -2;
}

int playOneGame(int games, int number_of_games, char guess) // CHANGED
{
    //return true is guess = answer otherwise return false
    // return true; // CHANGED
    char answer = 'a';  // CHANGED
    while (games <= number_of_games)
    { // CHANGED
        answer = 97 + rand() % 27;  // CHANGED
        cout << "Lets play game " << games++ << '\n';
        for (int number_of_guesses = 0; number_of_guesses < 5; number_of_guesses++)
        {

            cout << "Enter your guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
            if (guess > answer)
            {
                cout << "The letter you are trying to guess is before " << guess << "\n";

            }
            else if (guess < answer)
            {
                cout << "The letter you are trying to guess is after " << guess << "\n";

            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Your guess is correct! \n";

                break;
            }

        }
    } // CHANGED
    cout << "The answer you were looking for was " << answer << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```